# ExecutorService or new Threads in asynchronous jax-rs

Tags: jax-rs, executorservice, jersey-2.0

I've been looking over [Asynchronous services in jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html), I see that we delegate the processing to a new thread and let it handle returning the response. I have two approaches to thread execution

1. Creating anonymous threads and starting them in the resource method itself
2. Using ExecutorService to make a fixedThreadPool and delegating thread execution to executor

I'm concerned that using 1 would mean writing more boilerplate code and using 2 would essentially mean that the amount of throughput I generate from the system is limited by the size of executor thread pool. I'm sure that such a situation is common and I'm looking for some tested patterns or implementations which would help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with option 2, you can use dependency injection using @Inject annotation and HK2 AbstractBinder to instantiate a Resource constructor or a member variable. This allows you to change the executor service used by the Resource (i.e., the type of executor service used by the Resource is configurable).